# How to solve Tree difference problem given node connections, node values and query? (Dijkstra's Algorithm)

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

Tree difference (Problem Code: TREDIFF). This is a problem from Codechef's May Lunchtime (Contest is over so Practice now). My code runs fine in other IDEs but I get a TLE error when I submit. I code in Python 3. But all help is appreciated. Here's the problem:

**Problem**

You are given a tree with N nodes (numbered 1 through N). For each valid i, node i has a value Ai.
You should answer Q queries. In each query:

You are given two nodes a and b.
Let S denote the set of all nodes on the simple path between the nodes a and b (including these nodes).
Find the minimum value of |Ax−Ay| over all pairs x,y∈S such that x≠y.

**Input**

The first line of the input contains a single integer T denoting the number of test cases. The description of T test cases follows.

The first line of each test case contains two space-separated integers N and Q.

The second line contains N space-separated integers A1,A2,…,AN.

Each of the next N−1 lines contains two space-separated integers u and v denoting that nodes u and v are connected by an edge.

Each of the last Q lines contains two space-separated integers a and b describing a query.
Output

**Output**

For each query, print a single line containing one integer ― the answer to the query.

*Does anyone have an idea on how to make it faster?*

```
from collections import deque

INFINITY = float("inf")
Zero = 0

class Graph:
    def __init__(self, datasheet):
        graph_edges = datasheet

        self.nodes = set()
        for edge in graph_edges:
            self.nodes.update([edge[0], edge[1]])

        self.adjacency_list = {node: set() for node in self.nodes}
        for edge in graph_edges:
            self.adjacency_list[edge[0]].add((edge[1], edge[2]))

    def shortest_path(self, start_node, end_node):

        unvisited_nodes = self.nodes.copy()  
        distance_from_start = {
            node: (0 if node == start_node else INFINITY) for node in self.nodes
        }

        previous_node = {node: None for node in self.nodes}

        while unvisited_nodes:
            current_node = min(
                unvisited_nodes, key=lambda node: distance_from_start[node]
            )
            unvisited_nodes.remove(current_node)

            if distance_from_start[current_node] == INFINITY:
                break

            for neighbor, distance in self.adjacency_list[current_node]:
                new_path = distance_from_start[current_node] + distance
                if new_path < distance_from_start[neighbor]:
                    distance_from_start[neighbor] = new_path
                    previous_node[neighbor] = current_node

            if current_node == end_node:
                break 

        path = deque()
        current_node = end_node
        while previous_node[current_node] is not None:
            path.appendleft(current_node)
            current_node = previous_node[current_node]
        path.appendleft(start_node)

        return path, distance_from_start[end_node]


T = int(input())

for k in range(T):
    N, Q = map(int, input().split())
    Values = list(map(int, input().split()))
    nodes = []
    queries = []
    datasheet = []
    for i in range(N - 1):
        a, b = map(int, input().split())
        cost = Values[b - 1] - Values[a - 1]
        datasheet.append((a, b, float(cost)))

    for j in range(Q):
        c = list(map(int, input().split()))
        start = c[0]
        end = c[1]
        queries.append(c)
        graph = Graph(datasheet=datasheet)
        returned_path, returned_distance = graph.shortest_path(start, end)
        if returned_distance == INFINITY:
          print(Zero)
        else:
          print(int(abs(returned_distance)))
```

Comment: Why did you tag this as C++?

Comment: Have you tried running your code with pypy3? Still it gives TLE?

Comment: Official editorial is here: https://discuss.codechef.com/t/trediff-editorial/67092. Your solution is completely incorrect and it just happens to output the right answer to the sample test case by chance. In the future, make sure you prove your solution works or at least try a bunch of cases and analyze the complexity of your solution before implementing it. This way, you are less likely to implement solutions that will never work.